# How to have referenced document inside collection with conditions

Tags: mongoose, mongoose-schema

My schema is as follows:

foodtruck.js

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var Schema = mongoose.Schema;
var Items = require('./items.js');


var FoodTruckSchema = new Schema({
    foodtruck_name:String,
    foodtruck_location:String,
    foodtruck_rating:{type:Number,default:5},
    foodtruck_total_votes:{type:Number,default:0},
    foodtruck_tag:String,
    foodtruck_timing:String,
    foodtruck_cusine:String,
    foodtruck_img:String,
    foodtruck_logo:String,
    item_list: [ {type : mongoose.Schema.ObjectId, ref : 'items'}]
},{ versionKey: false });



module.exports = mongoose.model('foodtruck',FoodTruckSchema);
```

items.js

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var Schema = mongoose.Schema;

var ItemSchema = new Schema({
    no_of_times_ordered:Number,
    item_name:String,
    item_tag:String,
    item_category:String,
    item_illustrations:[String],
    item_stock:Number,   //0 available 1 last 5 items 2 not available
    item_quantity_ordered:{type:Number,default:0},
    item_price:Number,
    item_img:String,
    no_of_likes:{type:Number,default:0}
},{ versionKey: false });

module.exports = mongoose.model('items',ItemSchema);
```

Now, I want to have foodtruck which has such itemlist that, all the items inside it should have **no_of_times_ordered** greater than 4000. For that I am putting quesry as below:

```
 foodtr.find({
        'item_list.no_of_times_ordered': {
            $gt: 4000
        }
    }, function(err, items) {
        if (err) res.json({
            status: '404',
            message: 'there is no data available'
        });
        res.json({
            status: '200',
            message: 'popular items list',
            data: items
        });
    });
};
```

But here, I am getting empty list,so how can I have itemlist according to the requirement told above?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you are querying wrong, you cant use `item_list.no_of_times_ordered` for a referenced document. you need to use `populate` for that, and for only selective items, use `match` to `query` the condition inside `populate`.

Try this:

```
foodtr.find({}).populate({
    path : 'item_list',
    match : {no_of_times_ordered : { $gt :4000}}
}).exec(function(err, items) {
    ...
});
```